# How to generalize delegates in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to create a delegate sequence builder similar to the following (which is useful for stubbing in unit tests):

```
    public class StubSequenceBuilder<T>
    {
        private readonly Queue<Func<T>> _sequenceQueue = new Queue<Func<T>>();

        public StubSequenceBuilder<T> Next(Func<T> func)
        {
            _sequenceQueue.Enqueue(func);
            return this;
        }

        public Func<T> Build()
        {
            return () =>
            {
                var func = _sequenceQueue.Dequeue();
                return func();
            };
        } 
    }
```

The sequence builder creates a `Func<T>` that returns a different value every time it's called.

However this only works for a delegate that has no parameters and returns a value. Is there a way to generalize this class to support any delegate?

I know that type constraints don't support delegates; is there anything else in C# that can be used to achieve this?

Comment: The delegates do have a same base class [System.Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx). However, I don't think it works for your scenario. What would you do after you get the delegate?

Comment: There is no simple efficient way to do this.

Comment: @DannyChen I would just assign it to the stub that will be called in a test and provide a different value every time it's called (depending on how the sequence is setup).

Comment: @nbilal So your code knows how to invoke the method, which means it should know the signature of the delegate to invoke.

Comment: @DannyChen Yes, but I am trying to create a sequence builder that I can reuse for any signature.

Comment: @nbilal C# doesn't allow generic constraints for a delegate, but IL does. You can use [this lib](https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody).

Comment: Schabse is correct; there is no simple efficient way to represent this in the C# type system. There's no generalization over `Func<R>`, `Func<A, R>`, `Func<A, B, R>` and so on. Generalization across generic arity is simply not a concept that was ever embedded in the type system.

Comment: @DannyChen I'm actually developing for UWP where there are more security constraints (e.g. Reflection.Emit is not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in C# directly that can acheive this but you can use something like the following text template (*.tt):

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

<#

var maxArguments = 5;

for(int i=0; i < maxArguments; ++i) {

    var argTypes = string.Join(", ",new string[i+1].Select((x,j)=>"T"+j).ToArray());
#>

public class StubSequenceBuilder<<#= argTypes #>>
{
    private readonly Queue<Func<<#= argTypes #>>> _sequenceQueue = new Queue<Func<<#= argTypes #>>>();

    public StubSequenceBuilder<<#= argTypes #>> Next(Func<<#= argTypes #>> func)
    {
        _sequenceQueue.Enqueue(func);
        return this;
    }


    //...
}

<# } #>
```

Output (*.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class StubSequenceBuilder<T0>
{
    private readonly Queue<Func<T0>> _sequenceQueue = new Queue<Func<T0>>();

    public StubSequenceBuilder<T0> Next(Func<T0> func)
    {
        _sequenceQueue.Enqueue(func);
        return this;
    }


    //...
}

public class StubSequenceBuilder<T0, T1>
{
    private readonly Queue<Func<T0, T1>> _sequenceQueue = new Queue<Func<T0, T1>>();

    public StubSequenceBuilder<T0, T1> Next(Func<T0, T1> func)
    {
        _sequenceQueue.Enqueue(func);
        return this;
    }


    //...
}

//...
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Not exactly what I am looking for but it's a way of generating the different variants of `StubSequenceBuilder`